# CSS and Table/Tr row sizing

Tags: html, css, html-table, row

I created a table and I have the following problem. I have a row with Table Headings as the first line. The size of the second row and I think the size of the letters in the second row is different than in the third row.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>1</th>
  <th>2</th>
  <th>3</th>
 </tr>
<tr>
  <th>510px x 45px</th> *Letters also seem to be bigger
  <th>510px x 45px</th>
  <th>510px x 45px</th>
 </tr>
<tr>
  <th>510px x 37px</th>
  <th>510px x 37px</th>
  <th>510px x 37px</th>
 </tr>
</table>
```

**Attached:**

- Picture showing ROW 2

[image: Row 2]

- Picture showing ROW 3

[image: ROW 3]

I am sure that I have exactly the same code for the two rows because I copy / paste Row 3 code to Row 2 but the problem persists.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you show your CSS?  Also, are there any scripts running on the page that might manipulate tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was clearly different, because obviously in the second row you write 510px x 45px, whereas in the third row you write 510px x 37px..

**(510px x 45px) <> (510px x 37px)**

Comment: ???? What are you talking about? Did you read the provided information? I am stating that I copied and pasted the code from row 3 to row 2. I don't specify the weight, or height manually in any point!